# I have a button, when I click the button, the background will be white. When I click again, the background will be restored

Tags: reactjs, next.js

> ```
> const Profiles = () => {
>     const [style,setStyle] = useState("cont2 text-white bg-dark mb-3");
>     const changeStyle = () => {
>     setStyle("cont2")
> }
>
> //card body
> <div className="card text-white bg-dark mb-3"> 
> <button onClick={changeStyle}>change</button>
>  </div>
> ```

I have a button, when I click the button, the background will be white. When I click again, the background will be restored.

> `````
> ````
> //style
> .cont2 {
>             background-color: white;
>             align-items: center;
>             border-radius: 16px;
>             padding: 1px;
>             color: black;
>           }
> `````

https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: sorry, when i click again the background will change to its old color

Answer (score 0):

> if you want toggle class this code will help

```
 const Profiles = () => {
        const [style,setStyle] = useState(false);
        const changeStyle = () => {
        setStyle(!style)
    }
    
    //card body
    <div className={`${style ? "cont2" : "card"}text-white bg-dark mb-3`}> 
    <button onClick={changeStyle}>change</button>
     </div>
```

Comment: In fact, when I click the button again, I want to tell it to go back to its old color.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yeah it will work like this https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-germain-w0128?file=/src/App.js